# Android PopupWindow placement based on available screen size

Tags: android

I want to create my custom popupWindow in android. I have 2 problems in hand
1. How to place the popupwindow(left,right,top,bottom) based on available screen size. e.g.
button to which the popupwindow is linked 
a. If it is placed in Top Left, It should open in bottom of button
b.If it is in Bottom left of the screen, popup should open either in right of in top of the button

2. How to attach a popup window to a view(e.g. a button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to define a layout for your popup windown.
Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Next, you create a class which handle your popup windown

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class PopupMenu extends PopupWindow
{
    Context     m_context;

    public PopupMenu(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        m_context = context;

        setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(context).
             inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, null));

        setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    public void show(View anchor)
    {
        // you can edit display location is here
        showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

You can use it easily with this code:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context);
popupMenu.show(view);
```

If you put a listview in your PopupWindow, setting the width to WRAP_CONTENT won’t work. In order to the set PopupWindow width properly, you’ll have to add this in the show() method :

```
 // force the popupwindow width to be the listview width
listview.measure(
                 View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,
                 View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
setWidth(listview.getMeasuredWidth());
```

I hope it can help your problem!
Nice to help you!

Comment: How this can be used to place the popupwindow according to available screen width.

Comment: Question was how to draw (above or below event location) according to available screen width (or height)

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout.setGravity(Gravity.<use any>)` to place the layout. Assuming the popup window uses that layout.

Also see this link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Comment: Example-The anchorview(button) is present in left bottom of the screen. Then the popup should come either in right or in top of the button.